# Difference of two tuples containing Long numbers

Tags: python, performance, tuples

I have two tuples of `Long` values. I need the difference of them, something like `x2-x1`.

```
x1 =
(2873120768, 2873122560, 2873123328)
x2 =
(2873121279, 2873122815, 2873123583)
```

expected result:

```
result = (511,255,255)
```

but it does not matter if it is tuple or list

I am looking for a way not to do it element by element if possible. Speed is a constraint. I searched for it but couldn't find an answer.

Thank you in advance

Comment: Do you mean the sum of differences? Element-wise? What have you tried?

Comment: your variable assignments - `x1 =
(2873120768L, 2873122560L, 2873123328L)` in Python 3.4.2 creates invalid syntax error.

Comment: @hagubear 3.x doesn't have `long` any more. It's worth being familiar with https://docs.python.org/3.0/whatsnew/3.0.html

Comment: I am using Python 2.7 and these were the results. I assigned them with no 'L'!

Comment: @Angel yes, don't worry, the trailing `L` indicates `long` integer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In pure Python fastest way will be to use [`map`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#map) with [`operator.sub`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/operator.html#operator.sub):

```
>>> from operator import sub
>>> map(sub, x2, x1)
[511L, 255L, 255L]
#If you want tuple as output
>>> from itertools import imap
>>> tuple(imap(sub, x2, x1))
(511L, 255L, 255L)
```

If that is not enough switch to Numpy:

```
>>> x1_arr = np.array(x1)
>>> x2_arr = np.array(x2)
>>> x2_arr - x1_arr
array([511, 255, 255])
```

Let's time them:

```
>>> x1 = (2873120768L, 2873122560L, 2873123328L)*10**5
>>> x2 = (2873121279L, 2873122815L, 2873123583L)*10**5
>>> %timeit map(sub, x2, x1)
100 loops, best of 3: 19.3 ms per loop
>>> %timeit tuple(imap(sub, x2, x1))
10 loops, best of 3: 19.9 ms per loop
>>> %timeit [j - i for i,j in zip(x1, x2)]
10 loops, best of 3: 38.2 ms per loop
```

Using [`iterools.izip`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.izip)(Python 2) or simply [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) in Python 3 will make the list comprehension version almost as fast as `map`:

```
>>> %timeit [j - i for i,j in izip(x1, x2)]
10 loops, best of 3: 20.5 ms per loop
>>> %timeit tuple(i-j for i,j in zip(x2,x1))
10 loops, best of 3: 40.5 ms per loop
>>> %timeit tuple(i-j for i,j in izip(x2,x1))
10 loops, best of 3: 25.1 ms per loop
#Numpy arrays
>>> %timeit x2_arr - x1_arr
1000 loops, best of 3: 469 µs per loop
```

Comment: Thanks but I'd rather the built-in functions :)

Comment: @Angel Then why are you saying speed is a constraint?

Comment: hold on! I have a question. I have a huge size of data to process, which takes lots of RAM and CPU. I'm not sure using the built-in functions makes it faster or needs less RAM?

Answer (score 4):

You can `zip` the tuples, the iterate over the pairs and perform your subtraction in a list comprehension.

```
>>> x1 = (2873120768, 2873122560, 2873123328)
>>> x2 = (2873121279, 2873122815, 2873123583)
>>> [j - i for i,j in zip(x1,x2)]
[511, 255, 255]
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/functions.html#zip) function (Make an iterator that aggregates elements from each of the iterables.) :

```
>>> tuple(i-j for i,j in zip(x2,x1))
(511L, 255L, 255L)
```

Answer (score 1):

here is basic:

```
>>> x1 =(2873120768L, 2873122560L, 2873123328L)
>>> x2 =(2873121279L, 2873122815L, 2873123583L) 
>>> tuple( x2[i] - x1[i] for i in range(len(x1)))
(511L, 255L, 255L)
```

Note: assuming that len(x1) and len(x2) are always the same

Comment: This will work assuming that len(x1) and len(x2) are always the same. @Hackaholic. If one of them is smaller or larger, the additional 0-padding may be required which OP hasn't probably mentioned anywhere in the question.

Comment: @hagubear Yes, let me add it in note

Answer (score 0):

You can use map/lambda while zipping the values

```
x1 =(2873120768L, 2873122560L, 2873123328L)
x2 =(2873121279L, 2873122815L, 2873123583L)
print map(lambda (x,y):y-x,zip(x1,x2) )
```

Comment: You don't even need the `lambda` you can just use `operator.sub`.